# How to make correctly parse numbers with decimals in MVC actions with multiple cultures supported?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, globalization

I have MVC `POST` action requests that can't parse correctly numbers with decimals when there are many cultures supported, for example:

I have a pure form that doesn't use AJAX, it does the usual `POST`.
When the culture is `en-US`(web front-end), the action receives the `double`s/`decimal`s/`float`s with the decimal separator correctly set, meanwhile if the culture is `it-IT` those numbers are parsed as if there's no decimal separator, so `4,2`(actually `"4.2"` as in the note) becomes `42`.

[Note] In the `HttpContext.Request.Form` the numbers do arrive as `"4.2"`

Here's my request localization setup in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddRequestLocalization(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US");

            options.SupportedCultures =
                options.SupportedUICultures = new[]
                    {
                        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                        new CultureInfo("it-IT")
                    };
            options.RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>()
            {
                new AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider
                {
                    Options = options
                }
            };
        });
```

I looked up both on web and here without finding a solution to this, this is the first MVC project that this weird thing when they are moving it to multiple cultures support(before it was just `en-US`) meanwhile on other projects with same framework they didn't show this behavious. Any clue?

Comment: ASP.NET Core running on .NET 5 is not the same thing as "MVC 5", which runs on .NET Framework 4.x.

Comment: @RichardDeeming sorry, fixed with only `MVC` as a reference

Comment: The JSON standard does not support alternate decimal separators for numbers, and does not support thousands separators at all. There's a proper grammar for JSON at JSON.org, in several languages including Italian: https://www.json.org/json-it.html

Comment: @Corey Yeah, I get it and I agree, that's why numbers do still go on the wire as `4.2`, the issue here is why the framework can't still parse them correctly on it's own.

Comment: Odd. ASP.Net Core has used System.Text.Json since v3.0, and direct tests (altering CurrentCulture) correctly parses `4.2` regardless of culture set. I can't provoke it to parse it incorrectly as `42`. Which specific .NET and ASP.NET version are you working on?

Comment: @Corey .NET 5, same for ASP.NET